# Laravel 5.8 get current model info from a many-to-many relation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have three tables:

1. hotel
2. hotel_feature
3. hotel_feature_assing

"hotel" and "hotel_feature" both have a many-to-many relation.

In "hotel_feature_assing" I will save the id of the hotel and the id of the feature.

In the edit section I have a check box, I want to show the check box as `checked` if the current hotel (the one being edited) has the feature.

How can I check that the current hotel is already assigned to make my checkbox checked?

This is my Hotel Model:

```
  public function features()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(HotelFeature::class, 'hotel_feature_assigns');
    }
```

and in the HotelFeature model:

```
  public function hotel()
   {
     return $this->belongsToMany(Hotel::class);
   }
```

This is my checkbox:

```
@foreach($hotelfeatures as $key => $hotelfeature)
                    <input type="checkbox" name="idhotelfeature[]" id="idhotelfeature" value="{{ $hotelfeature->id }}"
                        style="margin-right:5px" @if ($hotel->is_feature)
                    checked
                    @endif><span class="font-weight-normal">{{ $hotelfeature->name_fa }}</span>
 @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an array of feature ids for an hotel to your view like:

```php
$hotel->features->first()->users->pluck('id')->all();
```

Where `$hotel` is the instance of the hotel you are viewing, then you can use that array of ids on your view's loop to decide what checkbox should be checked or not.